# How to set up workmail in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workmail

I would like to set up my `workmail` to get an incoming email but, I cannot see how and I have this message:
`Your domain's incoming mail is not enabled`

Comment: Where did the message (i.e. `Your domain's incoming mail is not enabled`) appear? Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

I think the original asker has abandoned this thread. But it is an issue that many people are struggling with and nobody has a really good answer. So I am going to show the screenshot as Flux was asking in the comment.

[image]

I am known to answer my own questions here, so by me getting on the case I will hopefully be able to catalyze a definitive answer.

I am managing my domain with AWS Rout 56 also, and surprised that there is nothing in workMail to just automatically set this up. You see that there are 3 DKIM related CNAME records that are said to be "Pending". This is odd, because I had many other records that needed setup, and I set them up manually and hit the retry button and every time it was discovering the DNS change immediately. Only with these 3 records it keeps with this weird "Pending" status.

Definitely in my case that 72 hours issue should not be an issue, it's not about DNS propagation. There is something else about this DKIM which is causing the "Pending" status.

**UPDATE**: This "Pending" status has now (~4 hours later) gone to "Verified". So there is nothing wrong with the DNS settings any more. Still the message remains "Your domain's incoming mail is not enabled."

Another thing that has been said elsewhere was to check the SES rules. I had a little clash trying to set up SES rules before I discovered WorkMail, then I went to set up WorkMail but deleted my bad SES rules. So now I added one simple rule back:

Under SES "Configure Email Receiving" there is one rule set called INBOUND_MAIL. In that under "View Active Rule Set" I created one rule:

Recipients: c...t.org
Actions: 
  1. WorkMail Action
     Deliver mail to WorkMail organization m-26...71

Which is the ARN of my WorkMail organization. So that's there.

Still, with all that it keeps saying inbound email is not configured. In Thuderbird I have set up outbound email with IMAP and SMTP just fine, but replying to the emails sent from the new organization will always bounce with:

550 5.1.1 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable

UPDATE: I haven't forgotten about this issue yet, still not figured it out, but I will and will report here.